# Wrong definition of function in template inherited class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have a problem with a template class and inheritance that I can't figure out.
Here are the used class.

An interface template class with a typedef:

```
template < const unsigned long Number >
class IA
{
protected:
    typedef  TemplateVector<Item*, Number > List; //template array

public:
    virtual List* getList() = 0;
};
```

The real class with same typedef (.hpp):

```
template < unsigned long Number >
class A : public IA< Number >
{
typedef  typename IA< Number >::List List;

public:
    virtual List* getList();

private:
    List* m_list;

};
#include "A.cpp"
```

The real class with same typedef (.cpp):

```
template < unsigned long Number >
TemplateVector<Item*, Number >* A< Number >::getList()
{
    return m_list;
}
```

The problem is with the .cpp definition of the `getList()` function.
It causes an error when compiling and I don't know why. The error is

> ```
> declaration is incompatible with "A<Number>::List *A<Number>::getList()
> ```

If I change:

```
typedef  typename IA< Number >::List List
```

to

```
typedef  TemplateVector<Item*, Number > List
```

it works fine but it's a redefinition and I want to avoid this kind of warning.
(Note that I need to separate into .hpp and .cpp files and I use integrity compiler)

Comment: Another way to solve this is to change the header in function definition (.cpp) to `typename A<Number>::List* A< Number >::getList()`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79fbe3febd01232b . In fact, this seems to be the most sensible way to do it.

Comment: It was as simple as this! Thanks for your help :)
I tried  A<Number>::List* A< Number >::getList() without the "typename" before. I was so close :)

Comment: the `typename` part was suggested to me by gcc, I myself always forgot it too. However, this does not solve the question you posted; I hope someone more knowledgeable will explain why your original code does not compile.

Comment: Side note: You declare your typename to be `protected` in `IA` and `private` in `A`, except you publicly expose functions that return objects of those types. Unless a user uses compile-time type inference, they cannot call your functions with an explicitly-typed variable. Either make your typedef's public, or make them protected and also make the functions protected. I would prefer the former because what's the harm in exposing a typedef to the user here? (For more on what I mean, see [this code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1829c4d004e68490)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand the rationale for this happening. Consider a simpler example demonstrating the same problem

```
template<class T>
struct base {
    typedef int foo;
};

/*
struct other{};

template<>
struct base<float> {
    typedef other foo;
};
*/

template<class T>
struct test {
    static typename base<T>::foo bar();
};

template<class T>
int test<T>::bar() {   // (1)
    return 2;
}
```

This produces the following error with gcc:

```
a.cpp:22:5: error: prototype for ‘int test<T>::bar()’ does not match any in class ‘test<T>’
 int test<T>::bar() {
     ^
a.cpp:18:34: error: candidate is: static typename base<T>::foo test<T>::bar()
     static typename base<T>::foo bar();
                                  ^
```

Why does this happen? Consider what the compiler would think when it encounters the line (1). Even although no template instantiation is in progress (and therefore the compiler has nothing to substitute for `T`), it may try to match the header of function definition to its declaration. It sees that in the definition the return type is `int`, while in the declaration the return type is `typename base<T>::foo`. How can the compiler know that they will be the same type *for all* `T`s?

Obviously the compiler can not infer this, because it is simply not true. Indeed, if you uncomment the commented part, you will find that for `T=float` the `base<T>::foo` will be `other`, not `int`.

So when the compiler hits the line (1), it can never be sure that *for each* `T` the `base<T>::foo` will be `int`. (In fact, for some `T`s the `base<T>` can have no `foo` member at all.) So if a compiler tries to check the return type *before* actual instantiation, it has no other way but fail.

I'm not quite good at the standard, so I can not support this explanation by the quotes from there; maybe I'm in fact wrong and there is another reason based on the standard.

And anyway, as I noted in the comment, you should not use `StaticInternalVersatileVector<Item*, Number >*` as a return type at all. The simplest and the most correct way is to use just `typename A<Number>::List*`.